# How do I copy and paste an error message in Pharo?

Tags: error-handling, debugging, smalltalk, pharo

Squeak was once innovative by giving people more than a dull error message: a debugger and go figure out!

However, nowadays there's a google, and now it'd rock to copy paste the error message, which is typically served as the title of a debugger window. How can I copy and paste that error message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way I know is `window menu > change title > ctrl-c`, alas this opens yet another window. The window menu is the second icon on the top left (if you use Squeak standard theme).

Might be cool to add a `copy error message` button to the error dialog though. Contributions are welcome!

Comment: Ah cool. I waded through the halos, found the label morph, debugged it, and then found the string there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want the full stacktrace, you can see the file PharoDebug.log generated in the same directory where the image is. Then you can open the file and just copy the content.